# Existence of left/right limits of bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis

Given a function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is bounded, is it true that for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c^-} g = d$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c^+} = e$ for some $d$, $e \in \mathbb{R}$?

In other words, do the left and right limts of bounded functions exist, even if those functions aren't continuous? I know it's of course true when $g$ is continuous and I (think) it's still true even when not. Since, intuitively the function doesn't blow up anywhere as it's bounded so the left/right limit should always be defined, even if they aren't equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, bounded functions can fail to have limits. It is true that unboundedness close to $c$ means the limit doesn't exist. However, you have missed another major way limits can fail to exist: oscillations.

For a simple example, consider
$$
g(x) = \cases{\sin(1/x) & if $x\neq 0$\\0 & if $x = 0$}
$$
which doesn't have a limit (neither upper nor lower) at $0$. (Put the function $\sin(1/x)$ into a graph drawer if you haven't seen it before, it's used rather often as a pathological counterexample in exactly questions like this.)

Or take the function
$$
f(x) = \cases{1 & if $x$ is rational\\0 & otherwise}
$$
which doesn't have limits anywhere.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense cheers. `Sometimes intuition fails in maths!